Modal window opens on any click
I've scoured half the internet but still can't find a solution. How to make a simple modal window that would open when clicking on any  tag on a website.
To clarify: when you click on any link on the website, it will open a modal window. Any help is very welcome.
I'm not good with js and its modules, but I tried opening the window via href, but for some reason it didn't produce the desired results

Im sorry there is no way we can sensibly help without seeing relevant code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and also give as full a verbal explanation of what you want to happen as possible.

Pls provide your code in a reproducible snippet. Not clear as well what you want to accomplish. See this if it can help <a href="https://www.yourTarget.com" target="_blank">click me to open window</a>

To achieve "when you click on any link on the website, it will open a modal window" I am gonna provide you a very simple approach.
1. Bootstrap:
Add following links inside head and right before closing the body:
Inside head:
<link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

Before </body>:
<script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

Then use a or button and add following two data attributes: data-bs-toggle="modal" and data-bs-target="#modalName"
Then create a div and add following attributes: class="modal fade", id="modalName", tabindex="-1", and aria-hidden="true"
Inside that div you can add your data which you wanna display. You can also call same modal from multiple buttons by adding same data attributes.
Here is a complete example:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="mb-3 p-3">
      <nav class="d-flex gap-5">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalName">Link</a>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalName">Link</a>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalName">Link</a>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalName">Link</a>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalName">Link</a>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <main class="px-3">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed recusandae repudiandae accusamus autem, est nihil blanditiis! Laborum dicta consequatur cupiditate pariatur, tempora ad. Magni fugit pariatur eos ad voluptates! Accusantium! <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalName">Link</a>
      </p>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalName">Link</a> dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed recusandae repudiandae accusamus autem, est nihil blanditiis! Laborum dicta consequatur cupiditate pariatur, tempora ad. Magni fugit pariatur eos ad voluptates! Accusantium!
      </p>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed recusandae repudiandae accusamus autem, est nihil blanditiis! <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalName">Link</a> Laborum dicta consequatur cupiditate pariatur, tempora ad. Magni fugit pariatur eos ad voluptates! Accusantium!
      </p>
    </main>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div
      class="modal fade"
      id="modalName"
      tabindex="-1"
      aria-labelledby="modalNameLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="modalNameLabel">Modal title</h1>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn-close"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Close"
            ></button>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis placeat libero doloribus cum optio quisquam consequuntur repudiandae nihil nulla. Eligendi recusandae, ullam totam deleniti ipsam doloremque culpa velit assumenda consequuntur?
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-secondary"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            >
              Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>



2. JavaScript
If you prefer not to use Bootstrap then you can get desired functionality by using simply JavaScript. Rest of the method is same to call same modal just script is different.
Here is the complete example:


var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var openModalBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.openModalBtn');
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];
var closeModalBtn = document.getElementById('closeModalBtn');

openModalBtn.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
  });
});

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
});

closeModalBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
});

window.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Modal</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <button class="openModalBtn">Open Modal</button>
        <button class="openModalBtn">Open Modal</button>
        <button class="openModalBtn">Open Modal</button>
        <button class="openModalBtn">Open Modal</button>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="openModalBtn">Open Modal</a> dolor
        sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Amet veniam architecto
        consequuntur hic iure magni quidem, laudantium velit, ipsa obcaecati
        eius voluptatum, accusantium similique fuga et reiciendis blanditiis
        nostrum ad!
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="openModalBtn">Open Modal</a>
      </p>
    </main>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h2>Modal Header</h2>
        <p>This is a simple modal example.</p>
        <button id="closeModalBtn">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



